# Как правильно реализовывать "корзину" в бд?

Tags: sql, база-данных

К примеру для своей работы я хочу сделать так

[image]

или всё таки правильно создавать новую таблицу для каждого заказа, к примеру: в которой 2 колонки ид и количество?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: *или всё таки правильно создавать новую таблицу для каждого заказа* 1) Клиентский код НИКОГДА не должен выполнять DDL, за исключением работы с temporary table. 2) Все корзины - экземпляры одной и той же сущности.

Comment: На каждый товар в корзине просто создаётся новая запись в таблице basket с полями user_id, item_id, item_count